# how to detect if a user is a bot within the on_message?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am creating a system the detects if a bot sent my bot a message, if so, it'll alert me to my server with a webhook. But unfortunately, it hasnt been working.

I tried `message.user.bot` but it doesn't work the way I intended it to. Is there a correct function to determine if the message author is a bot?

Comment: "but it doesn't work the way I intended it to" What is this supposed to mean?

Comment: @gre_gor that it didnt work.

Comment: "it didnt work" is not a proper problem description.

Comment: then what is? @gre_gor

Comment: It doesnt require that much detail, i just need the proper way to check if the message author is a bot @gre_gor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `message.author.bot`.
For example this:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        pass  # whatever here
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```